# Bind ConsoleLogger messages to TextBox

Tags: c#, wpf, msbuild

I am trying to write a simple IDE for C#. I have implemented Building projects like this:

```
        var path = ProjectPath;
        var props = new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            {"Configuration", "Debug"},
            {"Platform", "AnyCPU"},
            {"OutputPath", ProjectPath}
        };
        var pc = new ProjectInstance(path, props, "14.0");
        var logger = new ConsoleLogger();
        logger.Verbosity = LoggerVerbosity.Diagnostic;
        var buildParams = new BuildParameters()
        {
            DetailedSummary = true,
            Loggers = new List<ILogger> { new ConsoleLogger() },
            DefaultToolsVersion = "14.0"
        };
        var targets = new List<string> { "PrepareForBuild", "Build" };
        var reqData = new BuildRequestData(pc, targets.ToArray());
        BuildManager.DefaultBuildManager.BeginBuild(buildParams);
        var buildResult = BuildManager.DefaultBuildManager.BuildRequest(reqData);
```

I have a TextBox in my XAML file that I would like to bind with ConsoleLogger messages. However, the ConsoleLogger object works on a very different basis than `Control` objects in WPF. My initial intuitive idea was to simply write an Event Handler to handle errors and messages, but `ConsoleLogger` doesn't allow me to do that. How would I got about solving this problem?

Note: there are many `ConsoleLogger` classes around .NET, I am talking specifically about: `Microsoft.Build.BuildEngine.ConsoleLogger`

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.build.buildengine.writehandler(v=vs.90).aspx